# How to push notification by a device to another device in react native

Tags: javascript, push-notification, react-native, onesignal

Can anyone tell me how to push notification by a device to another device ? Maybe that’s good if it in One Signal , but no problem if also by firebase ?

For android

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use firebase.
Use need a server and a database.
You initialize firebase in your app. 
When user open your application you get token from firebase and send it to your server and in your server you store token for each user.
And then when a user wants to send message to another user, it call an api from your server to send notification to specific user.
And in your server you have firebase token for each user and by using that you can send push notification to that user with apis that firebase prepared.